# java Composition with back reference of owner class in owned class

Tags: java, composition

Owner Class:

```
class University {
  List<Student> studentCollection;
  public void addStudent();
  public void removeStudent();
}
```

owned Class:

```
class Student {
  String name;
  public void setName();
  public String getName();
}
```

Here University is composed of Students and if we delete university object, all its students are supposed to be deleted.

But i want to ask the Student what University it is in?
Can we change Student class to have the reference of University?

Proposed class

```
class Student {
  String name;
  University univRef;
  /* ... */
}
```

would this still be appropriate composition? In UML can this be marked as composition?
Or should it be changed to bidirectional association?

Note: Searching for the answer wasn't successful & struggled with formatting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is still a composition. The Students are still owned by the University and they are still killed when the University burns down.

Formally speaking, the first composition (without the back-reference), is modeled in a UML class diagram with a filled diamond on the University end, and an arrow on the Student end. The composition without the back-reference is then represented without the arrow. However, a lot of people are not very strict in applying the arrow, using the second notation also for a unidirectional composition.

To be clear you should model it with two arrows: One with a filled diamond from the University to the Student, the other without diamond from the Student to the University.

Comment: Thanks fishinear. So Composition isn't really a strictly unidirectional association. MS visio doesn't add arrow on Student's end.

Comment: Well, MS Visio is just a drawing tool, not a modeling tool. It won't get everything exactly correct. And as I said, it is common to leave out the arrow even for unidirectional composition. Formally, no arrow means "directionality undetermined" in UML.

Answer (score 0):

have a read through the docs of `java.lang.ref.*`

Answer (score 0):

Having a reference to the University as a Student and a reference from the University to all Students is a bidirectional association. It is also more fitting than a composition because a University is not composed of Students.

Make sure it is clear however that when you remove a Student from a University you also update that Student's reference to the University. These two operations should be done atomically, make sure to test it thoroughly.